# Hide or Remove content with JQuery

Tags: jquery

The CMS I'm using inserts code for a breadcrumb navigation on my pages, and I don't have the ability to edit it directly. Right now the breadcrumb looks like:

www.mysite.com » Home » About Us

I want to remove the "www.mysite.com" and the first »

How do I do that with JQuery? The HTML code looks like:

```
<span class="breadcrumbComponent">      

<a class="breadcrumb" href="/">www.mysite.com</a>&nbsp;<span class="breadcrumbseparator">&#0187;</span>&nbsp;<a class="breadcrumb" href="/en/">Home</a>&nbsp;<span class="breadcrumbseparator">&#0187;</span>&nbsp;<a class="breadcrumb" href="/en/about-us/">About Us</a>

</span>
```

So basically I just need to remove:

```
<a class="breadcrumb" href="/">www.mysite.com</a>&nbsp;<span class="breadcrumbseparator">&#0187;</span>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Well, the HTML code could certainly be improved. An UL element would be a better choice (since we have a list of breadcrumb items) in which case it would be an easy task to remove the first item...

Comment: Also, what's with the `&nbsp;`? If there is only one space between the A and SPAN elements, just use a regular space character.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have control over the breadcrumb code, which is why I need JQuery to manipulate it. :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.breadcrumb:first').remove();
$('.breadcrumbseparator:first').remove();
```

Comment: This is really close, but when I do this, I still have two extra &nbsp; (spaces) before the Home. I know I'm being nitpicky and I can probably just solve it with CSS, but is there another way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: I just added text-indent:-6px to the breadcrumbComponent and it made up for the extra spaces at the beginning. Good enough! ;)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) & jQuery [Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$('a.breadcrumb').remove();
```